# Spring tests failing with 404 when trailing slashes / missing from requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have my controller with a filter to allow for requests with and without the trailing slash /. This functionality has been implemented through the use of a filter located under the main package.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class TrailingSlashRedirectingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fullURL = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromRequest(request)
                .build()
                .toString();
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        if (fullURL.endsWith("/") && !uri.equals("/")) {
            fullURL = fullURL.substring(0, fullURL.length() - 1);
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY.value());
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, fullURL);
        } else if(uri.equals("")){
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY.value());
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, fullURL + "/");
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

I then added this to the config package inside the test directory:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<TrailingSlashRedirectingFilter> trailingSlashRedirectingFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<TrailingSlashRedirectingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new TrailingSlashRedirectingFilter());
        registrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/*"); // replace with your application's URL pattern
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

However, even though my application works fine with and without the trailing slashes, my test is still failing when I don't have a / added to it, even though I'm calling this configuration class on top of the class.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class,
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = TrailingSlashRedirectingFilter.class))
@Import(TestConfig.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class UserControllerTest extends BaseTestConfig {

    UUID userId;
    User userRequest;
    User userResponse;
    String jsonRequest;
    String jsonResponse;

    @MockBean
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    void testCreateUser() throws Exception {

        User user = userResponse;
        when(userService.createUser(any())).thenReturn(user);

        mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.post("/api/v1/ht/users").content(jsonRequest).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andExpect(content().json(jsonResponse))
                .andDo(document("create-user",
                        resource("Create a user")))
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Using this class now but the tests still only work if the trailing slash is applied.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Spring 2.7.5

Thank you.

Comment: in your WebMvcTest annotation you set excludeFilters to exlude your TrailingSlashFilter class. Maybe this could be a problem.

Comment: If I don't do this I get this other error Failed to load application: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'trailingSlashRedirectingFilter' defined in class path resource.

Comment: The filter is excluded but then reapplied through the TestConfig class which is being imported within the other annotation.